# Definition of the alternating tensor product in Ryan

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, tensor-products, tensors

In [chapter 1 of Raymond A. Ryan's *Introduction to Tensor Products of Banach Spaces*](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-1-4471-3903-4_1), the *alternating tensor product* is defined in the exercise section (see below).

However, while I would like to solve exercise 1.9, I don't even understand the definition. First of all, there is a round bracket on the lhs and a angular bracket on the rhs in the definiton of $x\otimes_ay$. Is this a typo? I guess not, since there are other places in the book before where this kind of bracket type mismatch occurs. But I cannot find the definition. Moreover, shouldn't $x\otimes y-x\otimes y$ be $0$?

So, I'd really appreciate if someone could help me understanding the definition and indicate how we can solve this task. I'd also be interested in the question, if we are able to complete this space of alternating tensor products with respect to the Hilbert-Schmidt norm (assuming $X$ is a Hilbert space, of course).

[image]

Comment: Ryan is perfectly right

Comment: @janmarqz He is perfectly right in which sense? Could you explain to me how I need to understand the definition? What does the expression $(x\otimes y-x\otimes y\rangle$ mean?

Comment: Looks like typos: the $\rangle$s should be $)$s.

Comment: in the alternating case you should have $(x\otimes y-y\otimes x)/2$.

Comment: @AnginaSeng Thanks for the comment. That makes more sense. Do you know the answer to my Hilbert-Schmidt norm completion as well?

Comment: oops! I  was sleepy

Comment: @janmarqz No problem; Ryan is perfectly right, except where he is wrong ;).

Comment: what diverts me a lot was the confusion on $x\otimes y-y\otimes x$ you have